# Create a Toast that Comes From Top of Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, toast, android-library

I am wondering how do we **create a Custom toast** in Android that shows on the top of screen like this?

[image]

I came from iOS background and now I have to create custom controls like this.

Any pointers please?

Thank you

Comment: You can look into this [library](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar).

Comment: There are a lot of custom libraries built. just search android-arsenal.com

Comment: You can refer this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom Toast at screen top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988334/custom-toast-at-screen-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link: https://github.com/gfranks/GFMinimalNotifications, this is what you want i think and it is working fine for me.

output:

[image]

Or you can prepare custom toast like this:

```
View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtoast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **crouton** for this purpose.

***Description*** :

> A Crouton will be displayed at the position the developer decides.
>   Standard will be the top of an application window. You can line up
>   multiple Croutons for display, that will be shown one after another

Create a Crouton for any CharSequence:

```
Crouton.makeText(Activity, CharSequence, Style).show();
```

[more details on Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton), a **Context sensitive notifications for Android**

***there are many you can use for toast* describe [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/104)**

Answer (score 1):

try this ::

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Your string here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

add this line for position

```
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

creat customize toast layout, toast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:background="@color/yellow"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:padding="8dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="32sp"
      android:layout_height="256dp"/>
```

create toast using the layout above:

```
    static Toast t;

public static void show(Context c, String s) {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Toast(c.getApplicationContext());
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        TextView v = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
        t.setView(v);
        t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    TextView v = (TextView) t.getView();
    v.setText(s);
    t.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see, there are many solutions. But the easiest way is create a layout in your XML layout file, and make it invisible. When this view needs to be shown make it visible and start an animation.

Comment: Please include some code to show how the OP could implement this suggestion.